# How to use join in hibernate criteria following situation

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

We have two tables Family and Member, the relation between these two is Family has set of members in it but member don't have any family relationship within it.

I wanted get member using dob and family for that I am using Hibernate criteria API's but I am not getting how to write join query since members don't have Family instance with it. So not able to use  FetchMode. Any other way to achieve this ?

thanks in advance.
- Ravi Nikam.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to select - individual member / list of members / family with member collection on it? Can you clarify? Plus it'd help if you could either post your mappings or at least describe them better.

Comment: yeah, See I want to search for member using DOB and family from database. I want single matching member for given family whoever is top of the result of query. Using HQL it would be easy as specified below, but I want it thru criteria and for that I don't have family as property of member and I have set of members in Family instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you guys, I have resolved this with one of my colleague as under

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria
            .forClass(Family.class, "family")
            .add(Expression.eq("family.id", family.getId()));

                subquery.createAlias("members", "members")
                    .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("members.id", "m.id"))
                    .add(Expression.eq("members.DOB",Date));

                subquery.setProjection(Property.forName("members.id"));

                Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Member.class, "m")
                        .add(Subqueries.propertyIn("m.id", subquery));


            results = crit.list();
```

results has list of members i requested.

Answer (score 1):

instead of trying to do

```
from Member m join m.family f where f.name = ?
```

which is not possible, you could do the exact opposite

```
select m from Family f join f.members m where f.name = ?
```

I know, it's HQL not Criteria, but that's what I'm more fluent with. It should be trivial to "translate" this HQL to Criteria though.